# Is general (POSIX) shell language allowed in /etc/sysconfig/* scripts? Or are there restrictions?

Tags: linux, shell-script, configuration, services

In `/etc/sysconfig/*` scripts one can have ordinary `name=value` assignments, of course.

But these files are interpreted by `.` from a shell, aren't they?  Are there any restrictions upon the shell language that can legitimately (i.e. in accordance with whatever rules there are for the operating system) and portably (i.e. across multiple operating systems) be used in them?  Or can one use arbitrary (POSIX) shell language?

I am thinking of things like:

- complex assignments: `abc=/var/${logdir}`
- sourcing common "library" or "helper" scripts

[This RedHat documentation](https://centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-sysconfig.html) and [this OpenMandriva documentation](https://github.com/OpenMandrivaSoftware/initscripts/blob/master/sysconfig.txt) go into great depth on the various individual options that can be set, but are mute on the actual fundamental format of these files.

(The equivalent to `/etc/sysconfig` on Debian is `/etc/default`, which *does* have rules about the format.  [Debian's *Policy Manual* requires](https://debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#writing-the-scripts) that files in `/etc/default` "must contain only variable settings and comments in POSIX.1-2017 `sh` format".  This question is about RedHat's `/etc/sysconfig` though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short: it depends

longer:

Redhat and Mageia/Mandriva use a symbolic link for **`/bin/sh`** to point to **`bash`**, so when those are scripts, you'll get bash acting like sh, or bash itself, **depending** on whether the sourcing script uses bash or "sh".  There are both cases for both systems.

Not all of the files in **`/etc/sysconfig`** are scripts; some (such as **`/etc/sysconfig/partmon`** on my Mageia6 machine, or **`systat.ioconf`** on my CentOS 7) are just data.  Something reads that, but it's not done by sourcing a script.